# Using bundler in Rails 2 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working on a task where i am moving gems from config/environment.rb to Gemfile in rails v2.3.18.

In the project they are using gems like below which are no longer available.

```
gem 'resource-query', '0.0.1'
gem 'data_tiles','0.0.3'
```

Is there a way that i can create a gem from

```
vendor/gems/resource-query or vendor/gems/data_tiles,
```

so that i can bundle it in Gemfile.

What is the easiest way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of those gems exist in vendor/gems why don't you just do something like this in your Gemfile:

```
gem "resource-query", :path => "vendor/gems/resource-query"
gem "data_tiles", :path => "vendor/gems/data_tiles"
```